# Docker is not pointing to existing containers

Tags: linux, laravel, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I'm on Ubuntu and I am using docker for my Laravel application but after the restart, I can't execute commands like `docker-compose up -d`, `docker-compose restart`, `docker-compose exec backend PHP artisan migrate` anymore. I checked other solutions like killing containers running on that specific port but the problem keeps coming back. What seems to be the problem?

whenever I try `docker-compose up -d`, this is the result:
[Error Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7qwe.png)

My application is completely running, but somehow I can't execute Laravel artisan commands so I tried restarting it, but it's pointing to these containers instead of the ones that are currently running:

[Containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tdl8J.png)

Comment: try stopping the process on those ports first, the error shows those ports are occupied, maybe u didnt stop the process properly before

Comment: I did stop those processes. But when I tried to restart my laptop, It appears again, I mean, do I have to do it everytime I restart my computer? I'm the only one experiencing this one in my team.

Comment: I'm new to docker setup, hope you understand.

Comment: Can you post your docker-compose file here?

Comment: Just switch to the other ports like 8080

Comment: Run `netstat -tulpn` to see what's listening on the ports. `ps aux` or `htop` may also come in handy.